# preg_replace all dashes after space 2013-12-12 12-00-00 to 2013-12-12 12:00:00

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression has always been a rocket science to me. Can anyone out there tell me how to write preg_replace to convert 2013-12-12 12-00-00 to 2013-12-12 12:00:00.
I tried using

```
preg_replace("/-(?=\s)/", ":", $string)
```

and I know it is not correct because it is not giving the desired output.

Comment: Looharounds only look at the previous/next set of tokens - there is no "flag" used. In this case I would (for simplicity) capture everything of importance in different groups and rewrite/replace based on that. If you do wish to use lookarounds, the expand the assertion match (and switch to a lookbehind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just look for a space followed by three pairs of digits separated by hyphens, and replace with another space and the three pairs with colon separators:

```
$datetime = preg_replace('/ (\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/'," $1:$2:$3",$datetime);
```